# ping -a does not return hostname

Tags: ip, rdp, ping, hostname

The problem i am currently experiencing is with One of my Untangle boxes. We are using IPsec VPN, Microsoft Server 2003 for DNS. I cannot get RDP to work with hostname, FQDN, ONLY IP. When i use ping -a, the hostname does not resolve. This is only happening in one of our locations, setup is very similar on both sides.

2 DNS server on the network. Location A IP's 63.201.77.X, Location B IP range 192.168.2.X. Both DNS servers are server 2003. Transversal NAT is enabled. All outside traffic is resolving on 8.8.8.8 and all inside traffic is resolving to our ISP. Locacation A and B both have there own DNS server

Comment: Sounds like a name resolution problem. Can you provide more details on the infrastructure; DNS servers, DNS suffixes, etc.

Comment: 2 DNS server on the network. Location A IP's 63.201.77.X, Location B IP range 192.168.2.X. Both DNS servers are server 2003. Transversal NAT is enabled. All outside traffic is resolving on 8.8.8.8 and all inside traffic is resolving to our ISP. Locacation A and B both have there own DNS server

Answer (score 1):

You need to set up a DNS record for whatever server you're trying to RDP to. The fact that you cannot resolve it with ping /a means there's no reverse DNS record, and the fact that you cannot resolve it to IP means there's no DNS record for the host.

Add the DNS information to both your DNS servers.

Comment: I dont think that in our case this is the issue. your answer did help me find more information about the issue. It looks like in Location A's DNS Forward lookup zone there are duplicate pointers. I believe that this is the issue.